# HTTP Cacheing To Lessen Cluster Nodes?

Tags: web-server, hosting, cluster, cdn

I have been looking into using http caching for one of my projects on heroku. The site is serving primarily dynamicish (meaning that the actual contents doesn't change that often) iFrame's and javascripts.

If I am understanding http caching services correctly (ie CloudFront, Edgecast & Akamai also has a similar solution) I will be able to technically scale my server nodes down considerably so long as I set the ttl on the cache to a reasonable amount of time. I am thinking 24-48 hours which means there should be only one request to the server in that time right?

Am I correct with this assumption?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, something like CloudFront would allow you to dramatically reduce load.

If you use unique URLs for updated resources - like `script_201110091213.js` - you can even set a far-future TTL and just change the URL to the script whenever you change things in the script.